# Creating a raku module for zef upload

Tags: raku

I've created a new Raku module and uploaded with fez, all working fine.

dist.ini file in the top directory. There are directives such as ReadmeFromPOD which don't seem to do anything. Is this file still needed? Seems to be a legacy issue from perl modules for CPAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you do not need a dist.ini file in a raku module.

Are you using an automatic tool to initialize or prepare the module prior to  using fez? If so, then I would inspect the source of that tool to get an idea of why it is making a dist.ini.

Comment: Not using a tool to setup, I created dist.ini as I saw it in many other distributions.. Seems  awkaward to have to manually construct the Readme.MD file. Would be nice if it could be generated from my Module.rakudoc file.

Comment: Hopefully Liz's answer explains to you what's going on. Those `dist.ini` files you've been seeing were probably in distributions created using the popular distribution authoring tool Mi6. Yes, it *is* awkward to manually construct bits of a distribution that could be generated automatically -- hence tools like Mi6. Sounds like you should use it too. And maybe file an issue for the Mi6 repo suggesting changing the comment `; dist.ini` at the start of the `dist.ini` file to something like `; dist.ini (See https://github.com/skaji/mi6)` to point newbie / cargo cult members in the right direction?

Comment: https://github.com/skaji/mi6/issues/170

Answer (score 3):

The `dist.ini` file is used by [App::Mi6](https://raku.land/zef:skaji/App::Mi6).

It is **not** legacy.

Install App::Mi6 and you will get a tool that will build the README.md automatically for you out of the available Pod.

And it will also release your module to the Raku ecosystem if you have your credentials set up correctly.

Basically the cycle is:

```
mi6 new Foo::Bar
cd Foo-Bar
vi lib/Foo/Bar.rakumod   # make your module
vi t/01-basic.rakutest   # update tests
vi Changes               # add message describing changes
mi6 build                # build the README.md among other things
mi6 test                 # run the tests
mi6 release              # release the module to the ecosystem
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will try using mi6. It's not referred to  at all here: https://docs.raku.org/language/modules#Modules

Comment: kim - App::Mi6 is the most popular "helper" for making raku modules. I apologize for not checking that it generates a dist.ini (and I gather that it must do so for good reasons) - BUT I am not sure that the doc you mention 'should' refer to App::Mi6 since this is not a requirement of a raku module distribution and it is a module provided by an external author. Perhaps it would be an improvement to say "you can use a tool such as App::Mi6" in the docs. I suggest you post this as a doc improvement issue (there is a link on the doc page)

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum, to ease future work you might try the module management aid Mi6::Helper which drives App::Mi6 with an one-liner interface.